# javascript event not registered

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get a strange behaviour. In a web page i import some script and i define some js function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
}
</script>
```

When i click on a button i display a dialog (this block)
I took some info from the server... and insert it in the bookInfoBlock area

Finally i got

```
<div id="bookDialog" title="book info" style="display:none">
  <button type="button" id="addBook1">+</button>
  <div id="bookInfoBlock">
        <button type="button" id="addBook2">+</button>
  </div>
</div>



$('[id^=addBook]').click(function() {
  alert("book test");
});
```

When i click on button with addBook1, i see the alert... but not when i click on addBook2.
It's like this last one don't know the event and javscript

Comment: are you loading `addBook2` via ajax?

Comment: You have a typo in the both blocks of javascript: you're missing end `)`s on your jQuery event calls.

Comment: @ Krishna, ya loaded via ajax.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're loading `addBook2` dynamically via ajax. In that case use event delegation using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/). If the div `bookInfoBlock` is static & is present in DOM all the time, use this.

```
$('#bookInfoBlock').on('click', '[id^=addBook]'), function() {
  alert("book test");
});
```

or if you're not sure about the static parent, use this

```
$(document.body).on('click', '[id^=addBook]'), function() {
  alert("book test");
});
```

As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated and removed completely in version 1.9. For older versions use [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) instead of `on()`

```
$('[id^=addBook]').live('click', function() {
  alert("book test");
});
```

Comment: quotes around 'document' will look for a <document> element. Just do document or document.body

Comment: i get: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on'

Comment: actually he should place `$("#bookDialog")` instead of `$(document.body)` if you know the buttons will be only inside `#bookDialog`

Comment: @redfox26 - which version of jquery are you using.. for 1.7 & below use `live()` - updated in the answer.

Comment: @IliyaReyzis - absolutely.. but what if `#bookDialog` is loaded via ajax too?

Comment: it's not working, will check if i can update to a newer release... will need to retest all the application.

Comment: @redfox26 - are you sure that all the braces are closed properly?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `delegate` instead of `click` .

`live` isn't more used, there is `delegate` :

```
$(document).delegate('[id^=addBook]','click', function() {
  alert("book test");
});
```

Comment: work fine with this one.... but need to better understand all strange js behaviour i have in my application.

Comment: @redfox26 so you can vote it and tick it as the solution.thanks